# regex incorrect c

Tags: c, regex

Hey so I'm trying to get this regex to work and when I type in "Hello" as the sentences input and "H" afterwards as the rgx, what I thought was just a basic regex match is outputting that it's not there each time I try anything similar. It only matches randomly correctly.

```
typedef char String[128];

int main(void) {

    String rgx;
    regex_t CompiledRegExp;

    String sentences;
    fgets(sentences, 128, stdin);

    fgets(rgx, 128, stdin);
    if (regcomp(&CompiledRegExp,rgx,0) != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Something wrong in the regular expression\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (regexec(&CompiledRegExp,sentences,0,NULL,0) == 0) {
        printf("Yes, it's there\n");
    } else {
        printf("No, it's not there\n");
    }

    regfree(&CompiledRegExp);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Don't you need REG_NOSUB in the flags?

Comment: @austin: since their are no parentheses in the regex, `REG_NOSUB` is not going to have much effect, although it's arguably a good habit. I'd use `REG_EXTENDED`, too, but that has nothing to do with OP's problem either.

Comment: @rici: Actually, I was thinking in terms of the "only return success/fail" behavior. But POSIX says passing 0 for nmatches also does that, so nvm. Yeah, with the help of lldb I saw the \n. +1 for your answer.

Comment: `regexec` always returns success or failure, and you're not required to set `nmatches` to the number of captures if you don't need all of them (as you say, you can even pass 0 for `nmatches`). The advantage of `REG_NOSUB` is that a regex library *might be able to* optimize the compilation of the regex if it knew that parentheses were never capturing. (Although I don't think it's a common optimization.) But if there are no captures, then that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

From `man fgets` (emphasis added):

> The `fgets()` function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by `s`, until `n−1` bytes are read, or a `<newline>` is **read and transferred to `s`**, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. The string is then terminated with a null byte.

A newline character in a regex is treated like any other ordinary character: it only matches itself. So if your regex is `H` followed by a newline, it will only match a string in which an `H` is followed by a newline. In your example input, the `H` is followed by an `e`.